# Possible causes of memory error

Tags: ios, memory-management, swift3

I’m having a memory issue.  I get an error message “Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=…)  The error is elusive, and apparently timing-dependent.  On my iPad mini, it usually averages about 3 minutes between crashes, on my iPhone SE it averages 10 minutes, and on the simulator it has run for 20 hours without crashing.

I’m not successful in using the Zombie detector.  (See below for my experiences with it.)  So I’m trying to go over my code with a fine tooth comb to see what might be causing the crash.  What are the issues that might cause an allocation error?

My app is multi-threaded.  It takes sound from the microphone, processes it, and continuously updates the display with the processed results.  It’s written in Swift 3, so I’m not doing any explicit mallocs or frees.

I’m looking for places in the code that might cause an error.  The two things I’m looking closest at are weak references and unsafe pointers.  Are there any other common programming errors that could trip me up?

(The Zombie detector is useless.  The Apple Instruments User Guide says, “For iOS apps, use the Zombies template with the iOS Simulator, rather than a physical device.”  I’ve ignored the warning and tried it with my iPad mini, and I can’t get it to crash.  Everything runs at about 1/10 speed, and when I pause the recording, my OSX machine gets sluggish as well, displaying the spinning “Wait” cursor for minutes at a time.  The total memory allocation goes up and down, but stays within limits, so there is no major memory leak.  I’ve also run the Zombies instrument on the simulator as well.  It’s equally sluggish, and it still doesn’t crash.)

Comment: Are you able to catch the crash in the debugger?  Is there a stack?  Do you have blocks that capture `self` as `unowned`?

Comment: Yes, it shows up in the debugger.  Here’s the code it barfs on
           `let loByte = bytes[pos]`
           `let hiByte = bytes[pos+1] // breaks here`
The actual values vary, but this last time pos was 630.  There’s nothing unusual in the debugger about either bytes or the 630th and 631st elements of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case turns out to be thread safety.  If I set a UInt8 variable on one thread and read it on another thread, it can lead to a memory error.  The setters and the getters are not thread safe.

(I’ve been programming computers most of my professional life, mostly in C, C++, and Java.  I’m familiar with the multi-threading issues in these languages.  I’m new to Swift 3.  It simply hadn’t occurred to me up to now that setting and getting numeric variables was not an atomic operation — that an ill-timed access could cause a program to crash.  I’m going to have to drastically rethink my approach to concurrency with Swift.)